# SD over SPI (RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader)

Tags: drivers, sd-card, card-reader

I would like to use SPI to interface with an SD card. My laptop (running Ubuntu 16.04) incorporates the RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader which works perfectly in SD mode, but attempts to use it in SPI mode have not worked so far.

The kernel module currently used by the card reader is `rtsx_pci_sdmmc`.

Things I have tried so far:

- Remove the `rtsx_pci_sdmmc` module and load the `mmc_spi` module;
- Rebuild the kernel with only SPI drivers;
- As a desperate last resort I set the `mmc_host_is_spi(host)` to 1 in `/include/linux/mmc/host.h` and rebuild the kernel.

I'm starting to think that the card reader does not support SPI, however according to the SD specifications this should be supported.

How do I make the card reader talk SPI? Is this impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the specifications, SPI mode is mandatory for SD memory and SDIO cards[1]. However, the SD **host** controllers do not necessarily support this mode [2]:

> ...This mode (SPI) is a subset of the SD Memory Card protocol, designed to communicate with SPI channel, commonly found in Motorola's (and  lately  a  few  other  vendors')  microcontrollers.

I'm still not sure if the RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader's microcontroller supports mode, but I guess it does not.

- [1] https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/pls/pdf/partE1_300.pdf
- [2] https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/pls/pdf/part1_410.pdf